# What data type can be used to store all values of a single column from a table in Oracle PLSQL?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

What data type can be used to store all values of a single column from a table and can i use these all values in IF ELSE statement to compare it with a single Char value?

Comment: An array if they are the same type? What are you trying to solve?

Comment: I'm trying to compare a Character with a list of column values and if that entered value is not present in my list then throw error.

Comment: Stores all of the values in a HashSet if they are unique or an array if they are not and then do the comparison

Comment: Ok Thanks Mate, appreciate it.

Comment: Much better method would be store each known value in a separate row in a lookup table with a unique constraint.  Then place a FK from where you are storing the character being validated. The database then takes care of the validation, without any IF-THEN-ELSE condition written on your part. And maintenance of the list is reduced to a table update.

Comment: Why can't you do everything in the database, in plain SQL? Leave the data where it is, and write a simple query to find values that contain your character.

Comment: Server memory is a limited resource, so how many values are we talking about, and how many sessions will need to do this at once? SQL queries are quite good at finding a value in a column. It's still not clear what the issue is.

Comment: I simply need to know if a character which i entered is present in that particular column. if no then throw error. i need to implement this in oracle forms. so will i get an example query for it?

Comment: What do you need to do if the character IS found in at least one value in that column?

Comment: Saying that you "need to implement this in **oracle forms**": does it mean that you'd be actually *searching* through a "column" in a tabular layout block in a form? Or is it really a column in a table in a schema?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a minimal PL/SQL procedure that will do nothing if at least one value in a given column contains a user-provided character, and throws the **no data found** error if the character is not found anywhere in the column.

```
create or replace procedure error_if_char_does_not_match(c varchar2)
as
  x number;
begin
  select 0 into x
  from   scott.emp
  where  instr(ename, c) > 0 and rownum = 1;
end;
/
```

Note the `rownum = 1` condition - without it the query may return more than one row (so we would get a different error, and we don't want that). Moreover, we can stop as soon as the first match is found - we don't need more than one.

Usage examples:

```
exec error_if_char_does_not_match('K')

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.




exec error_if_char_does_not_match('Q')

Error starting at line : 24 in command -
BEGIN error_if_char_does_not_match('Q'); END;
Error report -
ORA-01403: no data found
ORA-06512: at "MATHGUY.ERROR_IF_CHAR_DOES_NOT_MATCH", line 5
ORA-06512: at line 1
01403. 00000 -  "no data found"
*Cause:    No data was found from the objects.
*Action:   There was no data from the objects which may be due to end of fetch.
```